# iPad Black Screen on Interface Rotation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, rotation, orientation

I have a universal application created in storyboard mode. It is set-up to automatically rotate to the current orientation. When the iPad is rotated, it should go through the following code BUT all I get is a black screen.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    self.view = landscape;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(90));
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0);
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    self.view = landscape;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(deg2rad*(-90));
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0);
} else {
    self.view = portrait;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1004.0);
}
} else {

}
}
```

Why are all these problems arising here? What is going on and how can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Debug Console Result of: `po [landscape recursiveDescription]`
I end up with this response: Can't print the description of a Nil object

**EDIT:** Black Screen still appears even though the UIViews are linked to their outlets.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your method.  When the breakpoint is hit, run this in the debugger console: `po [landscape recursiveDescription]`.  Paste the output into your question.  Then run this: `po [portrait recursiveDescription]`.  Paste the output into your question.

Comment: @robmayoff when I type in this: po [landscape recursiveDescription] after (gdb), I end up with this response: Can't print the description of a Nil object. I have tried it on every line starting after the second conditional statement. I am not sure if I am doing this right, as I am not familiar with the debug console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `landscape` variable is nil.  That's why you are getting a black screen.  You need to set it to a UIView.

Comment: Using IBOutlets and @Prop/Synth I have set a UIView as the landscape outlet, but it still gives a black screen

Comment: Did you verify that `landscape` is not nil when `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is called, using the debugger or `NSLog`?

Comment: I went through every line in the snippet above and entered that command in the debugger and got the same result. I think it is a problem with the communication between views, I made a test app and the same thing happened.

Comment: If it tells you "Can't print the description of a NIL object", then `landscape` is nil.  You need to think about why it might be nil.  Maybe you didn't load this view controller from the nib.  Maybe you changed the value of `landscape`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I am using storyboards (sorry for not clarifying), could that be the limitation? No custom landscape views in storyboard mode?